# Accessing Linux terminal via team viewer

Tags: linux, remote-access

I can access to a remote CentOS machine using TeamViewer. However, I only need access to the terminal similar to Putty. Is there any way to access only terminal only?

Generally, my main concern is reaching a computer which has no valid (public) ip address.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to connect to a system without a stable public IP address, all include a way for the concerned system to make its location known to a system that wants to connect to it. The most common ways are:

1. Connect the machine to your infrastructure by means of a VPN, e. g.
   OpenVPN.
2. Set up dynamic DNS, e. g. afraid.org, and connnect using the
   name.